# Extract third level of folder structure stored in MySQL field

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I'm using the following regex (https://regex101.com/r/Kt9sNj/1) in PHP to get all the files in the third level of a directory:

```
/^(\/[^\/]*){1,4}\/?$/m
```

Then if I have the following data:

```
/home/myuser/folder_example/first_file.txt
/home/myuser/folder_example/second_file.txt
/home/myuser/folder_example/third_file.txt
```

I get:

```
first_file.txt
second_file.txt
third_file.txt
```

I try to use this in a MySQL query that contains an array of a json object.

My Query is:

```
SELECT data->'$.files' AS File 
FROM table 
WHERE user = 'myuser';
```

And I get:

```
["/home/myuser/folder_example/first_file.txt","/home/myuser/folder_example/second_file.txt","/home/myuser/folder_example/third_file.txt"]
```

But when I use that regex on my sql query:

```
SELECT data->'$.files' AS File 
FROM table 
WHERE user = 'myuser'
AND data->'$.files' REGEXP '^(\/[^\/]*){1,4}\/?$';
```

I need to get this (all files under that directory):

```
["first_file.txt","second_file.txt","third_file.txt"]
```

It doesn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: The string doesn't match the regular expression.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've edited the question with multiline regex, the link to the regex website and the result that I need in the query. Thank you!

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 0):

The function [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) returns 1 if the pattern matches and will return the full match as the pattern does match the example strings.

In [your pattern](https://regex101.com/r/tAruNK/1) you are repeating a capturing group, which will capture the last value of the iteration in group 1, but it still contains a leading forward slash that you don't want in the output.

What you might do is match the first `/`, and then use a quantifier `{3}` to repeat exactly 3 times a part ending on a `/` using a non capture group.

Then capture the filename in group 1, and refer to that group using `'$1'` in the replacement using [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace)

```
^/(?:[^/]*/){3}(\S+\.[^.\s]+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V3ax8n/1) | [Mysql with replace demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6bZ5rWqegHeyfKyeT48rJ6/0)